# In large JS apps where do I put custom methods to libraries and plugins

Tags: javascript, directory-structure, application-structure

I have a fairly large javascript application mostly using jquery and knockout. Essentially I make one major separation in my folder structure `app` has all the code I have written and is further divided into constants, views, models, and viewmodels. Then I have `vendor` which is code I did not write like jquery, knockout, plugins, etc. The problem I am having is where do I put the stuff that falls in between. I Have written some custom bindings for knockout and extended some functionality of some jquery plugins and they are just sitting in the root of my `app` dir. What is a best practice or naming convention for this.

```
+app
 -- constants
 -- models
 -- viewmodels
 -- views
 jquery-plugin-extras.js
 knockout-bindings.js
 etc
+vendor
 jquery.min.js
 knockout.min.js
 jquery-plugin.min.js
```

Comment: A typical practice is to create a "System" or "Core" directory for all your system or core functionalities. You can also create a folder called "Plugins" to put all your plugins for jquery or knockout .etc. I would also change the name of your folder "vendor" to "lib" which is where most of the libraries live!

Comment: could you write out a folder structure like above in an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
+app
 -- system (or core) //contains core or system related generics
 -- config // single place to store your configurations, if you have just one, put it at the root
 -- plugins // all plugins or ko bindings here
 -- constants
 -- models
 -- viewmodels
 -- views
 -- main.js // any bootstrapping, initial configurations and such go in to this file.
+lib
 --jquery.min.js
 --knockout.min.js
 --jquery-plugin.min.js
```